# Magento - Need to customize cutomer login & registration form but the login form and registration form are coming from Persistent folder

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.5, magento-1.6, magento-1.7

I want to customize the style and text details in customer login and registration form in Magento.

I use the default theme. And I should edit the login page located in: 
`/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/form/login.phtml` and register.phtml for registration page.

My issue is when I make changes in the above files, nothing reflecting in the display/frontend. So I enabled the template hints from the admin and I could do it by changing the 'Current Configuration scope' to 'Main Store' instead of 'Default Config'. Now I got the phtml page is from:
'`/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/persistent/customer/form/login.phtml`'.

What is the difference between these two? If I edit the login page from the persistent folder, do I have to change anything in admin? Currently I am checking locally and using default theme.

Also if someone knows, please mention why the form is pulled from persistent?

Answer (score 1):

**Persistent Module**

This feature basically adds a **Remember Me** option to the login and registration page. Its add overwrite new feature to the existing modules.

Comment: Why it is happening so? I want /app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/form/login.phtml and register.phtml for login and registration page. Any clue??

Comment: Or is it safe to edit on files from the presistent folder? If i did so will I get messed up later?

Comment: @Nina: If you don't need remember me option then you can disable presistent module, after customize your login.phtml in customer module or you can customize  presistent module files. Its depends upon your need. second question : If you used create or used any custom module that overwrite login.phtml means that will messed up.